# Can I omit my medium mount from an emanation?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, mount

I would like to use [Gale Blast](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=917) while mounted, without hurting my mount. It creates an emanation, and it is unclear where the effect starts:

> Because the **sides of a creature's space are the starting point for the emanation**, an emanation from a Large or larger creature affects a greater overall area than that of a Medium or smaller creature. Unless the text states otherwise, **the creature creating an emanation effect chooses whether the creature at its center is affected**.

As the medium mount of a Small creature is in the same square, the first highlighted section would leave it out. The second highlighted section however talks only about the creature itself, not its full square.

(Large creatures occupy more squares than the rider, so they are affeced anyway)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It's ambiguous, but probably not.

The description of the [Emanation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=357) states:

> An emanation **issues forth from each side of your space**, extending out to a specified number of feet in all directions. For instance, **the bless spell's emanation radiates 5 or more feet outward** from the caster. Because **the sides of a creature's space are the starting point for the emanation**, an emanation from a Large or larger creature affects a greater overall area than that of a Medium or smaller creature. Unless the text states otherwise, **the creature creating an emanation effect chooses whether the creature at its center is affected**.

As you've pointed out, the majority of the sentences can be interpreted to mean that there is a gap in the center of the emanation, while the last sentence implies that the creature at the center is still part of the emanation. That's contraddictory.

The rules for [Size, Space, and Reach](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=445) and for [Mounted Combat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=463) confirm that that a creature's space is square, and that the mount and rider share their space, but they don't clarify the problem.

Hence, it's ambiguous what should happen when two creatures do share the same space in the center, because the only relevant rule contradicts itself.

That said, if the emanation were truly meant to have a gap at its center, I think that would be spelled out far more clearly. Moreover, the [depiction](https://2e.aonprd.com/Images/Rules/Rules354.png) of the emanation colors-in the spaces occupied by the medium and large creatures, indicating that there is no gap in the center space(s) of the emanation.

> [image: The Core Rulebook's depiction of 5 and 10 foot emanations from medium and large creatures]

For these reasons, it seems unlikely to me that you could use an emanation like Gale Blast without affecting your mount.

---

This isn't part of my argument, but the way the emanation's last sentence refers to **the** creature in the center of the emanation, gives me the distinct *impression* that this rule just doesn't account for multiple creatures sharing the same space. Under that lense, it wouldn't even matter whether there is a gap at the center, because (as far as this rule is concerned) the only creature that could be at the center is accounted for in that last sentence.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the rule "...the creature creating an emanation effect chooses whether the creature at its center is affected" means that there's a gap, just that the caster gets a choice over affecting them.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes

There's a bit more relevant text under the rules for [emanations](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=357):

> **An emanation issues forth from each side of your space**, extending out to a specified number of feet in all directions.

If you and your mount share all spaces together, then your mount would be a "creature at the emanation's center", and could be excluded from the effect per the rest of the emanation rules.

As you've noted, there is an oddity that this isn't the case for large/larger mounts. The rules for [mounted combat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=463) include a few mentions of how the rider can count as being in all of the mount's spaces, but only in specific circumstances that don't apply here:

> You occupy every square of your mount’s space for the purpose of **making your attacks**.

> Anything that affects multiple creatures (such as an area) affects both of you as long as you’re both in the area. You are in an attacker’s reach or range if any square of your mount is within reach or range

There isn't additional guidance about how a caster would determine which square they actually are in for the purposes of an emanation's effects, so it could make sense to unify how it works for attacks and defensively, in that the caster counts as occupying every square of their mount's space. Very much in the realm of GM discretion without further clarification either way.